# facebook c# SDK get albums and images

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-c#-sdk

what i am trying to achieve should be simple by theory but hell by implementation, if you think otherwise please help.

so what i am trying to achieve here is that I have my facebook page which I created a developer acount for it, and what i want is to take albums from the page to my website.

I am using the latest stable facebook sdk for .net 6.8.0, and i am assuming that the graph api is on v2.2.

this is the code i am using below to get the access token and access my albums

```
        try
            {

                var fb = new FacebookClient();
                dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
                {
                    client_id = "---my application number---",
                    client_secret = "---my application secret---",
                    grant_type = "client_credentials"
                });

               var fb2 = new FacebookClient(result.access_token);
               dynamic albums = fb2.Get("my application number/albums");

               foreach (dynamic albumInfo in albums)
               {
                   try
                   {
                       dynamic albumsPhotos = fb2.GetTaskAsync(albumInfo.id + "/photos");

                   }
                   catch (Exception Exception)
                   {
                       throw Exception;
                   }
               } 

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
              throw e;
            }
```

The data returned in the dynamic albums variables is empty, the thing that confused me more is when i use facebook graph api explorer the call work fine and it return the albums. so what exactly i am missing.

I also read in some threads that you can access your albums without the secret password if they are public but that didn't work for me either i tried it in javascript but no joy.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To get info from your own Facebook page, you need a **User access token** instead of an **App access token**. See this for a walkthrough: http://www.thepcwizard.in/2013/02/working-with-facebook-c--sharp-sdk.html

Answer (score 0):

Since this is your page, it should be pretty easy to retrieve your own photos using Windows PowerShell and http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com Get-FBAlbums.